# Issues with isotope appending

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope to build a smooth grid gallery. Currently I am having issues with the append feature:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#appended

If I call the append like this

```
$('#loadMore').click(function(){
    val='<div class="content-box masonry-brick img11"><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 290px; height: 163.36666666666667px; "><div class="portfolio-more"><div class="portfolio-icon"></div></div></a><div class="content-box-content"><h3 class="post-info">Lifestyle / People</h3><h2>Street Life</h2></div></div>';

    var $container = $('#grid-gallery');
    $container.isotope( 'appended', val)

    return false;
  });
```

Then isotopes spits out the following error msg:

```
[content] has no method 'filter'
```

If I add positioning to the div, then it works fine, except the new element is loaded to that position and remains fixed.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this? I have a similar problem where anything I try to insert or append returns the "has no method filter" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
$container.isotope( 'appended', val);
```

To

```
$container.isotope( 'append', $(val) );
```

Or you could do this if you want it cleaner....

```
$('#loadMore').click(function(){

    val= $('<div class="content-box masonry-brick img11"><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 290px; height: 163.36666666666667px; "><div class="portfolio-more"><div class="portfolio-icon"></div></div></a><div class="content-box-content"><h3 class="post-info">Lifestyle / People</h3><h2>Street Life</h2></div></div>');

    var $container = $('#grid-gallery');
    $container.isotope( 'insert', val );

    return false;
});
```